# how to download hackerrank problems in pdf?

Tags: pdf, download

When we open up a problem on http:www.hackerrank.com, there is an option to download the problem in pdf format. Here I want to download all the hackerrank problems from algorithm domain. It will take near about 3-4 hours if I download them all one by one by clicking the button again and again and it will be the most tedious work I'd have ever done. Is there any way to download them all at once using either a program or some other way?

Comment: this has nothing to with algorithms

Comment: In fact, I was to download the problems from algorithms domain!

Comment: your question is about downloading files from a server via some specific software, **not** about algorithms -.-

Comment: apart from that this is no question for SO, unless you want to code the tool on your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a command line prompt you can do this with a simple one-liner:

```
for i in `seq -f "%03g" 1 79` ; do curl -L "https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler$i/download_pdf?language=English" > hr_euler_$i.pdf ; done
```

Just change `1` and `79` to the numbers of the first and last problems you want to download.

This will save all the PDFs in the current directory with filenames of the form `hr_euler_001.pdf`, `hr_euler_002.pdf`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, It works for projecteuler problems, but I wanted a solution in general.
but thanks a lot it gave me an idea "what i am looking for is not possible."
But on the other hand I assure I'll reply at my own!